# Why does TypeScript assume all elements of a destructured array match the source array's item type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

This throws no TypeScript errors (with my current config):

```
private static testDestructuring(): [string, string] {
  const [a, b] = ''.split('|');
  return [a, b];
}
```

But the JS equivalent violates the return type by returning `['', undefined]`.

```js
const testDestructuring = () => {
  const [a, b] = ''.split('|');
  return [a, b];
}

console.log(testDestructuring())
```

Is there a config switch I can use to help TypeScript catch that violation? Is there something about this situation that makes the potential error un-knowable by a static type analyzer?

Comment: Typescript cannot adequately wrap all of JavaScripts dynamic nature into a static typesystem. At some point, it will always fail and you as a developer have to fix logical errors that the typesystem did not catch. I had many cases were that infering was useful.

Comment: Assuming that all elements of the array have the same type is OK, and that's what the `string.split` result adheres to. The assumption that shouldn't have been made here is that the array has at least two elements - but afaik TypeScript (and for that matter, most type systems) doesn't track array sizes.

Comment: Looks like [this TypeScript pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/17765) might be related, but I'm having trouble deciphering how to take advantage of it.